# Obter parâmetro no .click igual passamos no onClick - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte iterator que possui botões de excluir que são carregados dinamicamente:

```
<s:iterator value="form.listaCooperativa" id="lista" status="lista_status">
    <s:if test="#lista_status.odd == true">
        <tr>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <tr class="linha-alternada">
    </s:else>
    <td align="center">
        <s:a href="javascript:;" onclick="abrirFormAlterar('%{idCooperativa}');" title="Alterar">
            <s:property value="pessoaJuridica.nrCpfCnpjFormatado" />
        </s:a>
    </td>
    <td align="left"> <s:property value="pessoaJuridica.nmEmpresarial" /></td>
    <td align="left"> <s:property value="apelido[0].nmApelido" /></td>
    <td align="center">
        <sisprocer:botao key="mantercooperativa.label.button.excluir" title="Excluir" id="excluir-dialog-confirm-link"/>
    </td>
</s:iterator>
```

Esses botões de excluir abrem um dialog:

```
function configuraPopups(){
    $('#excluir-dialog-confirm').dialog({
        autoOpen  :false,
        modal    :true,
        resizable :false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancelar": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");  
                //excluir(idCooperativa) QUERO ENVIAR O ID AQUI!
            } 
        }
    });

    // Dialog confirm link
    $('#excluir-dialog-confirm-link').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('%{idCooperativa}'); //QUERO RECEBER O ID AQUI
        $('#excluir-dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

}
```

Porém gostaria de obter o idCooperativa na dialog do objeto relacionado, igual como se estivesse enviando por exemplo = onClick('%{idCooperativa}');

Tenho problemas de utilizar o onClick pois o botão já esta padronizado para submit devido ao framework, ou seja, preciso recuperar dessa maneira para que pudesse enviar ao método relacionado com o parâmetro ao clicar em ok, como por exemplo:

```
"Ok": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");  
    excluir(idCooperativa);
}
```

Como consigo receber esse parâmetro nesse local? 
Lembrando que para cada botão tenho um id diferente.

Comment: Esse `id="excluir-dialog-confirm-link"` é gerado várias vezes? Não pode gerar id's repetidos.

Comment: Amigo eu vou te dar um conselho de rico: Troque esses IDS por classe. na classe você pega o valor, pega o id, pega o que quiser.

Comment: @Sam, verdade não tinha pensado nisso, porém não houve nenhuma sinalização de erro quanto a isso, qual você acha que seria uma boa solução?

Comment: @RiscadoOoOoOeRabisCadoO problema que é sistema legado e deve se manter a padronização.

Comment: Se voce colocar dois IDS REPETIDOS AO FINAL DO PROJETO... VOCE VAI TER UM LEGADO FANTASMA.

Comment: Acesse www.meuposto.ml/1.html para poder tentar te ajudad

Comment: Não dá erro, mas repetir id's causa problemas. Se vc não consegue alterar isso, pode selecionar o botão por outro atributo, tipo `$("#lista [title=Excluir]")`

Answer (score 0):

Stenio, você pode receber como parâmetro o evento de clique na função e, a partir dele, utilizar a função preventDefault() para impedir que o comportamento do Submit ocorra. Então você poderá fazer a manipulação de que deseja.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: sim mas pra usar o prevente default eu devo utilizar o .click e não onClick, para o .click eu não tenho o submit, porém não consigo passar o parâmetro, essa é minha dúvida

Comment: Você está usando qual framework? Todo elemento botão expõe o evento de clique com as caracteristicas que comentei, talvez no seu caso exista uma camada a mais...